# If Type (...) Python Wanting to do basic math but with an automated message

Tags: python

Please Note: I'm teaching myself Python and do not know some of the proper terms

Hi, I'm making a sophisticated multipurpose Code. My intention was to type in a calculation and an automated message would show but I'm not sure what to type in the brackets next to "type" (3rd line) to allow the user to type before the automated message shows, here is what I have ATM:

```
if type("Calculations"):
    print("Please enter a calculation")

if type():
    print("There you go!")
```

Comment: I also Just made an account to ask this question so sorry if i messed up the format

Comment: Apostrophes are ', not `.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, but to get input you want to use `raw_input` on Python 2 or `input` on Python 3. `type` gets the type of the object inside the parentheses.

Comment: `type` has nothing to do with typing on a keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get user input from the keyboard, use:

```
data=input("prompt")
```

So in your case:

```
calculation=input("Please enter a calculation ")
```

This will print `Please enter a calculation` and then expects you to type something.

Comment: tried it , got an error to do with an indented block

Comment: Expected an indented block

Comment: Did you do a full python tutorial? If not [here](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_course.php) is good own for python3, [here](https://www.python-course.eu/course.php) the same one for python2.

Comment: thanks for the help, i will comment if i still have any problems